# Filter string array with edittext

Tags: android, arrays, string, filter

```
String[] cities= {"Madrid","Barcelona","Valencia","Seville","Zaragoza","Malaga","Murcia","Palma"}
```

How can I filter this string array with the edittext. For example I will type "ma" in the edittext. Then; string array will filter like this (or create new string array);

```
String[] cities= {"Madrid","Malaga","Palma"}
```

Could you please help me. Thanks.

Comment: What have you tried? Here is the hint - `addTextChangeListener()` of `EditText`

Comment: Do some research before posting question here . Use `autocompletetextview` if you are showing them as list . otherwise use a `textWatcher`.

Comment: I googled seriously. And I didn't find, I am sure it is not simple. I already tried addTextChangeListener(), autocompletetextview.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Convert array to list and use this:

```
editText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
            if(!s.toString().isEmpty()){
                List<String> city = filterCity(clubList,s.toString());
            }

        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

        }
    });

public List<String>  filterCity(List<String> cities,String searchValue){
    List<String>  newCity = new ArrayList<>();
    for(String city:cities){
        if(city.contains(searchValue)){
            newCity.add(city);
        }
    }
    return newCity;

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Android Programming can not change the json but by programming you do same as you want to do.

First you have to store all the values of JSON to POJO and by RecyclerView or ListView you can get same.

```
     EditText myTextBox = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.myTextBox);
     myTextBox.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

   public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
   }

   public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, 
     int count, int after) {
   }

   public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, 
     int before, int count) {

   }
  });
```

Answer (score 1):

```
        String[] cities= {"Madrid","Barcelona","Valencia","Seville","Zaragoza",
                          "Malaga","Murcia","Palma"}
        String[] resultCities=null;

        editTextSearch.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

               @Override
               public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
               resultCities = search(editTextSearch.getText().toString())
               }

               @Override    
               public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start,
                 int count, int after) {
               }

               @Override    
               public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start,
                 int before, int count) {

               }
              });

              public String[] search(String txtsearch) {
                        String arr[]=null;
                        int pos=0;
                        for (int i = 0; i < cities.length; i++) {

                            if(cities[i].contains(txtsearch)){
                                arr[pos]=cities[i];
                                pos++;
                            }
                        }
                        return arr;
                    }
```

Answer (score 0):

use AutoCompleteTextView for this.
example:

in your layout xml put:

```
 <AutoCompleteTextView
    android:id="@+id/autoCompleteTextView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_marginLeft="36dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="17dp"
    android:ems="10"
    android:text="">

    <requestFocus />
</AutoCompleteTextView>
```

and in your activity/fragment

```
public class MainActivity  extends AppCompatActivity {
String[] cities= {"Madrid","Barcelona","Valencia","Seville","Zaragoza","Malaga","Murcia","Palma"}
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    //Creating the instance of ArrayAdapter containing list of fruit names
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>
            (this, android.R.layout.select_dialog_item, cities);
    //Getting the instance of AutoCompleteTextView
    AutoCompleteTextView actv = (AutoCompleteTextView) findViewById(R.id.autoCompleteTextView);
    actv.setThreshold(1);//will start working from first character
    actv.setAdapter(adapter);//setting the adapter data into the AutoCompleteTextView
    actv.setTextColor(Color.RED);
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

If you are using list/grid view, than in adapter you should add filter method, you can find tons of answers if you search here, I recommend using filters in adapter.